# How to Show a Shortcode that is Inside in Select Field in ACF?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a shortcode called **[post_category]** and **[post_tag]** that will show the category name and tag in the front end when posted in a normal post. However, I want to add this inside the **Select Field** in ACF. I tried adding [post_category] and [post_tag] in the field but when I tried to select it, the front-end still shows [post_category] and [post_tag] instead of the actual category name or tag name.

What I want is when I select any of them, I want it to show the category or tag name. How can you achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Function to replace [post_category] and [post_tag] with the actual category and tag names.
function replace_shortcode_with_category_or_tag($value, $post_id, $field) {
    if (is_string($value) && ($field['type'] === 'select' || $field['type'] === 'radio')) {
        // Replace [post_category] with the actual category name.
        $value = str_replace('[post_category]', get_the_category()[0]->name, $value);

        // Replace [post_tag] with the actual tag name.
        $value = str_replace('[post_tag]', get_the_tags()[0]->name, $value);
    }
    return $value;
}

// Hook into 'acf/load_value' filter to replace the shortcode with category/tag names.
add_filter('acf/load_value', 'replace_shortcode_with_category_or_tag', 10, 3);
```

I  assumes you have a single category and tag assigned to each post. If a post has multiple categories or tags, you might need to adjust the code accordingly to handle multiple categories/tags. Also, make sure to use the correct field names and handle any error scenarios to ensure smooth functionality.